# LINQPad - connecting to Entity Framework on Azure

Tags: entity-framework, azure, linqpad

I have no problem connecting to my Azure database and running queries against it.

I have no problem creating a DbContext connection to an assembly that points to my Azure database; I can see the tables (entities). But when I try to run a query LINQPad throws an exception:

> ConfigurationErrorsException: Couldn't find type for class Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener.

Do I need a different driver? I looked at the list in LINQPad and didn't see an obvious choice.

UPDATE:
Following Mikee's suggestion I added a reference to the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.dll to the LINQPad query with no luck. Then I added a reference in the project to that dll. Now when I run the query I get the exception stack and a more useful message: "Not running in a hosted service or the Development Fabric."

I've clicked around and found nothing helpful but at least the problem definition is getting better.

Comment: What does the app.config look like for the assembly?

Comment: Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"

Comment: which is what Azure added to web.config when I installed it. I just updated to 2.3.0 and updated web.config but it still bombs out LINQPad unless I comment it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem. Commented out the

```
<system.diagnostics><sharedListeners>
```

section in web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding a reference (Query>Properties or F4) to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.dll located in Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure.NET SDK\v2.2\bin\plugins\Diagnostics folder (on my box)

Comment: Just did Mikee, thanks for the suggestion. Still getting the error.